# How can I convert a singleplayer game to a multiplayer? (Unity)

Tags: unity-game-engine, networking, scripting

I made a singleplayer game, and I want to convert it to a multiplayer.
The problem is, I have at least 30 scripts, and a lot of system, like Inventory, build system, crafting system, tree chopping system, a complete animation system, animals, and zombies, so pretty much everything. A full survival game.

And I don't really know where should I start, I tried to convert it with the Unity's own networking with the official manual, but I don't really know which scripts should I convert, and how.
And I have a game manager, and a full UI system on the scene, and I don't know that how can I convert them...

Can anybody help me?
How should I convert the whole project? Or where should I learn about multiplayer?

Comment: There should be a lot of tutorials for you to begin with online. Do not try to convert you whole project in a single step. Divide you problem in to pieces, learn them one by one. Start by connecting a client to a server(your own local). Next sync the movements on both screen etc.. You can also check _Photon for Unity._

Comment: I aldready know Photon, but I can't really use it.
Maybe I can learn it again.